# CMake include libraries with executable

Tags: boost, cmake

I am using CMake and trying to include libraries I use with the executable for distribution. One library I am using is boost for which I am using the statement

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED thread filesystem)
```

This works fine, but I cannot redistribute to a computer where boost is not installed.

I then tried to use `fetch_content` but when cpack generates the installer, the library files built still aren't included.

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES thread filesystem)
set(BOOST_ENABLE_CMAKE ON)
FetchContent_Declare(build_boost GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git GIT_TAG boost-1.80.0)
FetchContent_GetProperties(build_boost)
if(NOT build_boost_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(build_boost)
    add_subdirectory(${build_boost_SOURCE_DIR} ${build_boost_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

How can I package the library files with the executable?

Comment: What is your actual question? ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Comment: You may want to take a look at the parts of [the `install` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) that contain `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES`/`RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET`